# Resize panel by the controls in it

Tags: vb.net

I had labels in my panel programmatically but if the panel Height is set to 100
and I had 15 label with the `.Location.Y` increase 20 for each one something like this:

```
label1.Location = New Point(5, 20)
label2.Location = New Point(5, label1.Location.Y + 20)
label3.Location = New Point(5, label2.Location.Y + 20)
label4.Location = New Point(5, label3.Location.Y + 20)
...
...
...
```

In some point the labels added are not showing in the panel because this panel does not auto grow is height
**How can I make the panel height grow by the labels added to show all of them?**

Comment: `Panel.Height = label4.Bottom` ?

Comment: That was simple =) thank you Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more complete, you need to set the ClientSize of the panel, this will take into account any borders, scrollbars, etc.

[Control.ClientSize Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Panel.ClientSize = New Size(Panel.ClientSize.Width, label4.Bottom)`

MSDN